# Visa refusal for australia

Tags: visa, immigration, australia

I'm from Punjab, and applied for a student with spouse visa for Australia in subclass 573. My visa got rejected with:

> Your visa rejection is due to 573.224(a) migration regulation 1994.

I had scored 6 bands in IELTS when I had applied for my visa. I'm confused now and also very worried whether I can apply for an Australian visa once again or not. My new IELTS score is 6.5. Can I apply for Australia once again with 6.5 bands and by making my file strong?

The refusal was due to funds overall. No specifics were given; only the section number above was given in the refusal letter.

Comment: hire a migration agent would save you a lot of time in my experience. Because Australian migration law is very complex, most of the time, the migration dept staff would not be able to give you good advise.

Comment: Section 573.224(a) seems to have nothing to do with language competency.  Why are you concerned about your IELTS score?

Answer (score 7):

Ah, Australian bureaucracy. [Migration Regulations 1994](https://www.comlaw.gov.au/Details/F2012C00493/Html/Volume_4):

> 573.224      The applicant:
>                      (a)     satisfies public interest criteria 4001, 4002, 4003, 4004, 4005, 4012A, 4013, 4014 and 4020

Well, that's helpful, onto Schedule 4 [Public interest criteria](https://www.comlaw.gov.au/Details/F2012C00493/Html/Volume_6#_Toc329692222) then... which are so long I won't quote them here.  But basically, they think you're:

4001) a criminal (the [character test](http://www.findlaw.com.au/articles/4353/visa-applications-into-australia-the-character-tes.aspx))

4002) a terrorist

4003) an international bad guy

4004) owing debts to Australia

4005) contagious

4012A) underage and can't support yourself — if your rejection was "due to funds overall" (how did you figure this out?), this is most likely the cause

4013 & 4014) http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/855.gif (basically, a whole bunch of weird exceptions and counter-exceptions)

4020) you've lied in your application.

Note that your English ability is *not* at doubt in any of those, so a better IELTS score is not going to help.  You'll need to figure out the problem and address it before you reapply.  Call the Immigration help line and hope you run into somebody helpful?  It's a long shot, but you don't have many other options here.